# Does the Modifications Made In GNU Parted Affect the File System Table File?

Tags: fstab, android, parted, partition-table

My Nexus 7 (2013 WiFi) tablet PC has a corrupted partition table. I would now like to troubleshoot into Linux.

After loading GNU Parted on the tablet and making a new GPT table with 30 partitions byte by byte, I print out the table to make a final check and then quit. I then get a message saying the fstab needs to be reloading. The guide I have been following suggests reboot into the recovery. However, this is where my tablet shuts off and is bricked again. It is though the work done in GNU Parted isn't saving.

Is the /etc/fstab supposed to update? Does GNU Parted have any relation to fstab? I did try the 'cat /proc/mounts' command but it looked pretty empty. I also tried 'mount -a' but it just said the 'system', 'data' and two other partitions "no such file or directory".

This is the link to my original post

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/206400/reset-partition-table-for-nexus-7-2013-flo

This is link is the entire set of commands I issue when attempting to fix my partition table

https://pastebin.com/aJJ1R4Be

Answer (score 0):

You are using a non Android utility on Android.

The problem here is **Android has no actual fstab**. Some vendor implement a version in a weird place, but good luck using it

Gparted was never intended for Android device. Use a supported method instead, which will require root (or better yet, just don't)

Although Android is based on Linux, it is very loosely so

Comment: Are there any partitioning tools you can suggest for Android that would work, or or is there anything you can think of to get it work?

Comment: There is one thing I have noticed under the '/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1' directory is that under 'by-name' non of the 30 partitions I recreated are in there except for roughly 7. If somehow the partition names I set using GParted could show in this directory I might get closer to getting something working.

Comment: @willowen100 what you are using can't work. It requires a whole different OS. The built in sm command has basic functionality, and some apps that use root can do it